# Linux group permissions on a directory

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm trying to modify this Linux directory

```
drwxrwx---  2 root  testGrp   4096 dec 17 16:33 test2
```

I'm writing groups "user" which outputs this:

```
user : user adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare developer testGrp
```

I have group permissions rwx for users in the group testGrp, somehow I cannot read from the directory or create files.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your current directory, can you check with `pwd`? and can you show how you read from the directory or create files? which commands you used?

Comment: Did you open a new login shell or logout/login after adding testGrp to user?

Comment: Thx Nj0rd I tried rebooting my computer and then it worked. Weird though I thought my new group would take effect right away.